# Create nav menu one nav item is taller than container's height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation ([Sample Wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE9IO.jpg)) which has a colored background. The nav items are in a list, and at different resolutions. As the font size changes the nav container's height also expands or contracts. However, I want one of these items (the middle one) to have a larger height and break the bounds of the container.

Is the cleanest way to do this to set the height of the container to be equal to the height of the other buttons using javascript, or will that still always cut off the larger nav item? I can't seem to break out one of the items from the bounds of the container without doing absolute positioning which completely takes it out of the flow of the other list items, and I want the height of the container to stay consistent with the rest of the buttons. Any thoughts?

Comment: I dont think changing the height with javascript would help. What do you mean by `takes it out of flow` when you use position:absolute?

Comment: Sorry, I mean when I absolutely position the larger item it just falls over the next item like this [example](http://i.imgur.com/LgvRCv7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the item with `position:absolute` set as a style property.

You may need to create another element next to it with the regular height that will be hidden behind it to keep the width reserved.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was trying before, but I was missing the item hidden behind it. Is this considered a hack or is this a reasonable way to handle this? I basically just added an empty "spacer" list item that hides behind the actual one.

Comment: @user6495130 I think it's a reasonable way to do it. Thats how I would approach it. Nice and simple. If this solved your question, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
position:absolute
```

will do the trick but also consider about having an extra div (nested div) so it isolates from the bigger item.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, `position: absolute`. It is important to note that an absolutely positioned element will have its origin point at the nearest element with `position: relative` (or the root element), so if you set the parent container to relative, the absolute menu item will start there.